# how to recognise specific text with selenium?

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a short procedure where im clicking automatically on some links in my web, and I want to do this to find if I have error 500.

It looks something like this:

```
 private def lookForError500 () = {

    println("starting to look for error 500")

    val link1: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidebar > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a"))
    link1.click()

    val link2: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidebar > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a"))
    link2.click()

    val link3: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidebar > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a"))
    link3.click()
```

Now sometimes there are error 500, and when the error 500 page is coming on screen, there is a text I can identify that says "sorry, something went wrong".

How can I look for this text after each click...?

this is how the inspect element looks like on the error 500 page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can write a function to verify for the 500ERROR Text and call it on every link you click or as per your needs try This if Other Answers above should work until if the Error 500 Text is changing the position you can try this

```
  public void Verify_Error(){
    String s=driver.getPageSource();
    if(s.contains("Error 500")){

    }else{

    }           
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using xPath to identify the `<strong class=error-number>` element that holds the error number that is 500 in this case. 
This xPath String would do the thing:

`//strong[@class="error-number" and text()="500"]`

In Selenium you can use xPath by using the `By.xpath()` method.

All together it would look like this.

`By.xpath("//strong[@class='error-number' and text()='500']")`

Comment: I dont know why I get error that this element can't be located...I tried as you said by xpath and also by cssSelector.....but same error for both

Comment: You can try using chrome and typing the xPath statement in the console: $x('//strong...') that may help identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element By xPath ,css path or by id .
Then you can get the text of the element using **getText()** method.

```
val text = driver.findElement(By.xPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/p/strong")).getText();

if(text.equals("500")){
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: I dont know why I get error that this element can't be located...I tried as you said by xpath and also by cssSelector.....but same error for both

Comment: the xPath might be incorrect , Please use firebug plug-in and go to the <strong> element and right click to get the correct xPath.

OR 

Give some id to the <strong> element .Then you can directly get element by ID . This would be much simpler than xPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a particular element exists this way:

```
//call the function with the xpath

if(ifElementExistsByXpath("//p[text()='SORRY, SOMETHING WENT WRONG')]"))

{
   
               //do some operation

}

else

{

             //no error..proceed

}

public static boolean ifElementExistsByXpath(String elemXpath)
    
{
            
          int count=driver.findElements(By.xpath(elemXpath)).size();
            
          if(count ==0)
            
          {
                return false;
            
          }
            
          else
            
          {
                return true;
            
          }
    
}
```

you can also use the class name instead of text.